# HTML form that allows user to insert images between text paragraphs

Tags: html, asp.net, forms, image, textarea

I am making a web application with ASP.NET Core that allows users to create courses and lessons, and I want to give the users the ability to put images like diagrams, graphs or anything else between the text like in a word document. Is there a way to do that in a textarea for example?

Comment: You might need to use a rich text editor, something like CKEditor (https://ckeditor.com/). Or if you wanted more control you could write your own RTE (learn about `contentEditable`).

Comment: You can use a rich text editor. I used Summernote in my application and it works like a charm. https://summernote.org/